# Geckodriver: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I installed geckodriver since selenium is no longer compatible with recent versions of Firefox. For that reason, I had to modify code that had worked for scraping a website. I am having trouble selecting items in a dropdown list. In the code below, everything works up until "browser.select"; I get the error: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'select'. I am using Spyder on a Mac.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import     DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] =  '/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox'

browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)

browser.get("https://sonuc.ysk.gov.tr/module/GirisEkrani.jsf")

time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id('closeMessageButton').click()   

         browser.find_element_by_id('j_id112:secimSorgulamaForm:j_id115:secimSecmeTa   ble:0:secimId').click()
```

browser.find_element_by_id('j_id112:secimSorgulamaForm:j_id142').click()

## Loop through provinces

```
time.sleep(4)
il_sayisi =   len(browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi").find_elements_by_tag_name('option'))-1

for j in range(1,il_sayisi):
    j = j +1
    iller =     browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi").find_elements_by_tag_name('option') 
    browser.select_dropdown('j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi',iller[j].value)
time.sleep(2) 
ilce_sayisi =     len(browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id120:cmbIlceSecimKurulu").find_elements_by_tag_name('option'))-1
for i in range(0,ilce_sayisi):
    i = i + 1 
    ilceler = browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id120:cmbIlceSecimKurulu").find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    browser.select('j_id48:j_id49:j_id120:cmbIlceSecimKurulu',ilceler[i].value)
    time.sleep(5) 
    browser.find_element_by_id('j_id48:j_id49:j_id192').click()
    time.sleep(5) 
    browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:tabloBilgileriPanel:j_id440").click()
    time.sleep(5) 
    browser.find_element_by_id("j_id1114:j_id1115:j_id1121").click()
    time.sleep(7)
```

[EDIT: The last part of the code was edited to the following and now works]:

```
iller = browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi")
iller_options = iller.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
i_options = {option.text.strip(): option.get_attribute("value")
         for option in iller_options if option.get_attribute("value").isdigit()}

for k in sorted(list(i_options.keys()))[4:81]:
# iller
    iller = browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi")
    iller_options = iller.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    i_options = {option.text.strip(): option.get_attribute("value")
             for option in iller_options if option.get_attribute("value").isdigit()}
    iller_select = Select(iller)
    iller_select.select_by_value(i_options[k])

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Plese share DOM XML for dropdown control.

Comment: They are option inside select drop-down. Can u share options with select control.

Comment: These are first three objects in the list from the inner HTML (it goes through 81):  <option value="-1" selected="selected">Seçiniz</option>
 <option value="1">ADANA</option>
 <option value="2">ADIYAMAN</option>
 <option value="3">AFYONKARAHİSAR</option>

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

selectEle = driver.find_element_by_id('<id_of_select_control_containg_these_option>')

select = Select(selectEle )

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('ADANA')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('1')
```

so to use select method in selenium web diver  first you need to create the object of select class. Then you can use below methods:

```
select_by_index(index)
select_by_value(value)
select_by_visible_text(text)
```

Let me know if it help

Comment: I haven't figured out how to incorporate it into the code/loop yet.

Comment: All your option should be inside an element which is type select . Please put then xml of that control.

Comment: please share xml for : iller = browser.find_element_by_id("j_id48:j_id49:j_id108:cmbSecimCevresi")

Comment: If it my solution worked for you then please accept the answer.